# Does MongoDB support two 2-way synchronization

Tags: mongodb

We are looking at moving our data from IBM Domino to another backend.  One of the things Domino does really well is replicate (or synchronize as they call it) between a Server and Clients.  That means that Users can take their mailbox, or any other application DB, with them and work offline and when they have access to the server the "master" on the Server synchs with the "slave".

Does MongoDB support two 2-way synchronization? Assuming that it does, does it also support selective replication, where the data that is pushed out to the Client can be controlled at a field level.

Thx in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, MongoDB does not support two-way synchronization. It has master-slave replication, where all writes must occur on the master node before being replicated to the slave nodes. You can read about all the replication capabilities of MongoDB in their [documentation.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication/)

Comment: Thx for the prompt reply John. What a disappointment.

Comment: Do you know of any other NoSQL DBs that support 2-way synching... such as Couchbase or Redix?

Comment: If you have further questions, please edit the original or ask a separate one. Comments are for further explanation but not more questions :)

Comment: @Paulryan very late answer but there is CouchDB

Answer (score -2):

Couchbase does support Master/Master replication, through it's XDCR (Cross Datacenter Replication) function. http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/XDCR/xdcr-intro.html

Full disclosure - I work for Couchbase.

Comment: This question is mainly for MongoDB. I suggest you move your answer to this other question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94184/nosql-dbs-and-2-way-synchronization.