# NoSQL DBs and 2-way synchronization

Tags: nosql

I've been told that MongoDb does not, but do any NoSQL DBs support this functionality?

Comment: Is there a reason you restrict yourself to NoSQL solutions?

Comment: Freeware version availability is one.  Scalability and availability are others.  That being said, if we do not find one that supports 2-way synching, that would be a show stopper.

Comment: Can't beat Postgres. If you can engineer a solution with that, you'll be laughing

Comment: Thx for yours, Phil... We'll look into it.

Comment: Hey @Phil, You should check out Couchbase and Couchbase Mobile - http://bit.ly/MobileCB where it is NoSQL database and is known for its synchronization features.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the 2-way Sync feature using [Couchbase Mobile](http://bit.ly/MobileCB) (client-side) solution and on the backend using [Couchbase Server](http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/couchbase-server)

Can check out an example on this [blog post](http://blog.couchbase.com/ontime-with-couchbase)